# Adding new field to one attributes table based on the field on another attributes table in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, geopackage, timestamp

I have two Geopackage layers on QGIS 3.22.2. One first one (`LAST_ROUTES`) shows the random extracted lines (routes) from the Istanbul highway map. Second one (`LAST_POINTS`) shows the points generated on those lines by using Points along geometry from Toolbox. As it is seen in the table below, I added timestamps to each point. The points stand for the trajectory of a car moved on the route, recorded once in 40 meters. That is why 2 tables have matching osm_id. For example, it was spent 8 seconds on the route with `osm_id = 4885644`. Can we add this data to the `LAST_ROUTES` table, which shows that in the route with `osm_id = 4885644`, the car reached the endpoint in 8 seconds?

[image]

In addition, I need this field in `LAST_ROUTES` to be Date&Time type, same as the type of the timestamp in `LAST_POINTS` table.[image]

Comment: You can add the maximum timestamp, can add the minimum, and can subtract them (also all in one step), but those 8 seconds won't be a timestamp. Also, what is the difference between fid 2 and 3 in the LAST_ROUTES table?

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca Since they have different osm_id, they are different routes.
How can I apply the way that you recommended? Maybe after getting the result, I can turn it into Date&Time somehow

Comment: What type the timestamp field is? Is it Date&Time? Sorry about the osm_ids, I didn't see the difference.